# How to allow specific roles to access API using identityserver3.accesstokenvalidation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have an Identityserver4 that is providing access tokens to clients.

On my API, I want to be sure that client is allowed to access specific scope and  that User belongs to a specific role before I give this user access to API.

To do that I am using Identityserver3.accesstokenvalidation package.

```
 app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "Authority",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "MyScope" },
        });
```

This is blocking users that do not have access token from accessing my API, also it is checking if the provided scope is "MyScope".

My question is how do I also check that user has a specific role before allowing  access to API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` for specific controller. If you need more advanced logic with claims you need to specify your own attribute e.g. `AuthorizePermissionAttribute` and use it with controller `[AuthorizePermission("Preview")]`:

```
public class AuthorizePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string grantedPermission;

    public AuthorizePermissionAttribute(string permission)
    {
        this.grantedPermission = permission ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(permission));
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var claims = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        var permission = claims?.FindFirst(this.grantedPermission);

        return permission != null && Convert.ToBoolean(permission.Value);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "insufficient_permissions");

        actionContext.Response = response;
    }
}
```

Also you need to put in Startup.cs:

```
   JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
   {
      Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityProviderApi"],
      PreserveAccessToken = true
   });
```

Without `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap` it will return always Unauthorized status code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how would the controller understand that it should use this class to check Role? and what is [AuthorizePermission("Preview")]? can you add some explanation ?

Comment: You could put [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] for the controller that you want to protect (this logic comes from AuthorizeAttribute from .NET). [AuthorizePermission("Preview")] just example how to use your own attribute if you need more advanced logic, e.g. for checking permissions.

Comment: I c, thanks.. I already used [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] but it is blocking all the requests even that the access_token contains role:admin as user claim

Comment: I updated answer, please pay attention to InboundClaimTypeMap.